# Text Replacement - Strings & spaces

Tags: string, powershell, text, replace

My company has deployed Splunk to gather logs, and report system changes. 
Splunk uses two files - inputs.conf and server.conf to track the existing host name and report it to Splunk control.

If a host name changes (common in our environment) the system reports a "Broken Host Sanity check" Requiring that we log into each system and replace the old host name, with the new one.

This is difficult with 1000 systems in the field.

I want to automate this process, and I'm having issues with the script I've written (see below).

Both the inputs and server use this format for the .conf files (.conf is just a txt file with a .conf extension).

```
Host = systemname
```

The script below will currently read the text file, and then instead of replacing 'systemname' it will append the changes to the end of the existing value. ie. instead of `hostname1` ⇔ `hostname2` it does `Hostname2Hostname1`.

```
$InputsOLD = "host = *"
$InputsNEW = "host = $Env:COMPUTERNAME"
Get-Content "C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\system\local\inputs.conf" |
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$InputsOLD","$InputsNEW"} |
    Set-Content "C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\system\local\inputs_1.conf"

$ServerOLD = "serverName = *"
$ServerNew = "serverName = $Env:COMPUTERNAME"
Get-Content "C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\system\local\server.conf" |
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$ServerOLD","$ServerNew"} |
    Set-Content "C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\system\local\server_1.conf"
```

Comment: `-replace` uses regular expression. Your `$ServerOld` is not a regex. Use `'servername\s*=.*'` for the first part of the `-replace`

Answer (score 3):

The `-replace` operator matches based on a regular expression. So your match expression:

```
"host = *"
```

will end its match after it matches its first "host = " not including the host name, and that's what gets replaced, leaving everything intact afterwards. To include the host name in the match expression, use this regular expression:

```
"host = .*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular expression which uses a [zero length assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
to match anything on the line following the keyword (even a literal asterisk)

This script changes inplace, using the same file name on save.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\01\18\SO_54259368.ps1

Push-Location "C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\system\local"

$Clie = "inputs.conf"
$Serv = "server.conf"

(Get-Content $Clie) -replace "(?<=^host = ).*$",$Env:COMPUTERNAME | Set-Content $Clie
(Get-Content $Serv) -replace "(?<=^serverName = ).*$",$Env:COMPUTERNAME | Set-Content $Serv

Pop-Location
```